# Django Server Reports POST Request as GET; Drops POST Data

Tags: django, apache, post, get

On my local machine, if I use:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I can make POST requests to the server and they appear in the terminal with the word POST.

However, if I ssh into my remote server and also type:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then if I make a POST request to the remote server, it gets received but the terminal says that it is a GET request instead for some reason. The POST data is dropped from the request.

I am having a bit of difficulty determining where the problem is. I do not think it is with Django since runserver works fine locally, and I do not think it is Apache since I am using runserver on the remote machine. Could it be router settings of some kind?

Any suggestions on how to proceed with this problem is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To clarify, I am testing this by using a Google Chrome extension called Postman that allows you to manually send POST requests. When I tried this locally, I had CSRF token issues, but then I decorated the applicable view with csrf_exempt and now it works locally. However, the remote server is still dropping the POST data and reports the method as being GET.

Comment: How exactly are you testing this? Are you possibly missing a CSRF token on your test POST request?

Comment: I am using a Chrome extension called Postman to send the POST request. I don't know much about CSRF tokens, but I retrieved a CSRF token from another tab where I just made a normal GET request and took the CSRF token that session used (and then put that in as a value for csrftoken), I'm not sure if that is a viable way of doing it. Interestingly though, the Django server processes the request correctly, it just drops the POST data (and the generated logs record the request as being a GET request).

Comment: Clarified a bit about the CSRF token stuff in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this was something wrong with Postman, when I used curl to generate POST requests, I had no issues.

Still not sure why Postman worked locally but not remotely though.